# Segmentation Fault

Tags: ros, rosserial, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Everyone,

sorry for an other segmentaion fault question, but i really dont see it. Im generating on an arduino a message which has an array that holds multiple sensor readings. The arduino is publishing with 13.7Hz. On the ROS side i subscribe to that data and want to create for each sensor reading a single range message with an unique frame_id for a later transform.

Little Ros Graph:
/serial_node -> /range_data -> /sensor_state_publisher -> /ir_1_data , ir_2_data, ir_3_data, ir_4_data, ir_5_data , ir_6_data, ir_7_data

Every now and then i get a segmention fault error, when starting the node on the ros side. I tried to deallocate the used arrays in the destructor, to clear them and to rize them. When im changing the average rate to a higher value, the segmentation error accures more often. I also tried to set up the buffer size. Nothing helped. Did someone see my mistake, or is the hole programm bs and not usable for my need.

Here my code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <range_msgs/SensorStates.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Range.h>

class SensorStatePublisher
{
public:
    SensorStatePublisher()
    {
    state_listener = nh.subscribe<range_msgs::SensorStates>("/range_data",100000, &SensorStatePublisher::sensor_msg_callback, this);
    ir_1_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_1_data", 100000);
    ir_2_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_2_data", 100000);
    ir_3_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_3_data", 100000);
    ir_4_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_4_data", 100000);
    ir_5_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_5_data", 100000);
    ir_6_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_6_data", 100000);
    ir_7_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_7_data", 100000);
}

void sensor_msg_callback(const range_msgs::SensorStatesConstPtr &msg);
void publish_range_msg(void);
void populate_range_msg(void);
private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber state_listener;
    ros::Publisher ir_1_publisher,
                   ir_2_publisher,
                   ir_3_publisher,
                   ir_4_publisher,
                   ir_5_publisher,
                   ir_6_publisher,
                   ir_7_publisher;



 // Message Elements
    std_msgs::Header _header;
    int _radiation_type;
    float _field_of_view, _min_range, _max_range;
    std::vector<float> _sensor_ranges;

    // Range Messages, one for every Sensor
    std::vector<sensor_msgs::Range> range_msgs;
protected:
};

void SensorStatePublisher::sensor_msg_callback(const range_msgs::SensorStatesConstPtr &msg)
{
    _sensor_ranges.clear();
    // Save All Metadata
    _header = msg->header;
    _field_of_view = msg->field_of_view;
    _min_range = msg->min_range;
    _max_range = msg->max_range;

    // Save Every Arrayelement Of The Message
    for (int i = 0; i < msg->range.size() ; ++i) {
        _sensor_ranges.push_back(msg->range[i]);
    }
    _sensor_ranges.resize(msg->range.size());
}

void SensorStatePublisher::populate_range_msg(void)
{
    range_msgs.clear();
    // Populate New Range Message With Saved Data
    sensor_msgs::Range new_range;
    new_range.header = _header;
    new_range.field_of_view = _field_of_view;
    new_range.min_range = _min_range;
    new_range.max_range = _max_range;

    // Save Data In An Array of Ranges
    for (int i = 0; i < _sensor_ranges.size(); ++i){
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "ir_" << i+1 << "_link";
        new_range.header.frame_id = oss.str();
        new_range.range = _sensor_ranges.at(i);
        range_msgs.push_back(new_range);
    }
    range_msgs.resize(_sensor_ranges.size());
}

void SensorStatePublisher::publish_range_msg(void)
{
    // Publish All Elements of the Range Array
    ir_1_publisher.publish(range_msgs[0]);
    ir_2_publisher.publish(range_msgs[1]);
    ir_3_publisher.publish(range_msgs[2]);
    ir_4_publisher.publish(range_msgs[3]);
    ir_5_publisher.publish(range_msgs[4]);
    ir_6_publisher.publish(range_msgs[5]);
    ir_7_publisher.publish(range_msgs[6]);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "sensor_state_publishe");
    SensorStatePublisher statePublisher;
    ros::Rate r(10);
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        statePublisher.populate_range_msg();
        statePublisher.publish_range_msg();
        r.sleep();
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for every help and excuse my little noob cpp/ros programm. ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188823/segmentation-fault/) by [TwoBid](https://answers.ros.org/users/19927/twobid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-04**:
Where does your segfault occur? Check out this site: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

**Comment by [TwoBid](https://answers.ros.org/users/19927/twobid/) on 2014-08-04**:
Does not help to set the core file size unlimited....:(

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-08-04**:
Oh sorry, I posted this link that you run your node in GDB. There you get much more information about the segfault. To build in debug mode do catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug To build normal again do catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Everyone,

found my Problem. As Hendrix said, the Problem was that i wasn't checking the vector size in the publish_range_msg method. The Problem was that in the first moment i have not received any data through my subscriber. In that case the elements of my range_msgs vector were 0. That causes the segmentation fault. So here the Solution for everyone who has a similar approach :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <range_msgs/SensorStates.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Range.h>

class SensorStatePublisher
{
public:
    SensorStatePublisher()
    {
        state_listener = nh.subscribe<range_msgs::SensorStates>("/range_data",100000, &SensorStatePublisher::sensor_msg_callback, this);
        ir_1_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_1_data", 100000);
        ir_2_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_2_data", 100000);
        ir_3_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_3_data", 100000);
        ir_4_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_4_data", 100000);
        ir_5_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_5_data", 100000);
        ir_6_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_6_data", 100000);
        ir_7_publisher = nh.advertise<sensor_msgs::Range>("/ir_7_data", 100000);
    }

    void sensor_msg_callback(const range_msgs::SensorStatesConstPtr &msg);
    void publish_range_msg(void);
    void populate_range_msg(void);
private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber state_listener;
    ros::Publisher ir_1_publisher,
                   ir_2_publisher,
                   ir_3_publisher,
                   ir_4_publisher,
                   ir_5_publisher,
                   ir_6_publisher,
                   ir_7_publisher;

    // Message Elements
    std_msgs::Header _header;
    int _radiation_type;
    float _field_of_view, _min_range, _max_range;
    std::vector<float> _sensor_ranges;

    // Range Messages, one for every Sensor
    std::vector<sensor_msgs::Range> range_msgs;
protected:
};

void SensorStatePublisher::sensor_msg_callback(const range_msgs::SensorStatesConstPtr &msg)
{
    _sensor_ranges.clear();
    // Save All Metadata
    _header = msg->header;
    _field_of_view = msg->field_of_view;
    _min_range = msg->min_range;
    _max_range = msg->max_range;

    // Save Every Arrayelement Of The Message
    for (int i = 0; i < msg->range.size() ; ++i) {
        _sensor_ranges.push_back(msg->range[i]);
    }
    //_sensor_ranges.resize(msg->range.size());
}

void SensorStatePublisher::populate_range_msg(void)
{
    range_msgs.clear();
    // Populate New Range Message With Saved Data
    sensor_msgs::Range new_range;
    new_range.header = _header;
    new_range.field_of_view = _field_of_view;
    new_range.min_range = _min_range;
    new_range.max_range = _max_range;

    // Save Data In An Array of Ranges
    for (int i = 0; i < _sensor_ranges.size(); ++i){
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "ir_" << i+1 << "_link";
        new_range.header.frame_id = oss.str();
        new_range.range = _sensor_ranges.at(i);
        range_msgs.push_back(new_range);
    }
    //range_msgs.resize(_sensor_ranges.size());
}

void SensorStatePublisher::publish_range_msg(void)
{
    // Publish All Elements of the Range Array
    ros::Publisher *pubs[7];
    pubs[0]=&ir_1_publisher;
    pubs[1]=&ir_2_publisher;
    pubs[2]=&ir_3_publisher;
    pubs[3]=&ir_4_publisher;
    pubs[4]=&ir_5_publisher;
    pubs[5]=&ir_6_publisher;
    pubs[6]=&ir_7_publisher;

    const int n = _sensor_ranges.size();
    ROS_INFO("publishing %d range msgs",n);
    for (int i = 0; i < _sensor_ranges.size(); ++i){
        pubs[i]->publish(range_msgs[i]);
    }
    
/*    ir_1_publisher.publish(range_msgs[0]);
    ir_2_publisher.publish(range_msgs[1]);
    ir_3_publisher.publish(range_msgs[2]);
    ir_4_publisher.publish(range_msgs[3]);
    ir_5_publisher.publish(range_msgs[4]);
    ir_6_publisher.publish(range_msgs[5]);
    ir_7_publisher.publish(range_msgs[6]);*/
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "sensor_state_publisher_node");
    SensorStatePublisher statePublisher;
    ros::Rate r(10);
    while(ros::ok())
    {
        statePublisher.populate_range_msg();
        statePublisher.publish_range_msg();
        r.sleep();
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [TwoBid](https://answers.ros.org/users/19927/twobid/) with karma: 38 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Usually, segfaults happen where you derererence an invalid pointer, or use an invalid array index.

In your case, you're not checking the bounds of range_msgs in publish_range_msg.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2